# Appending text in string

Tags: java, string

I want to append a string at runtime but this code again add the previous word not to append new word.

Customer.java:

```
public String getCustomerQuestion() {
  return CustomerQuestion;
 }
public void setCustomerQuestion(String customerQuestion) {
CustomerQuestion = customerQuestion;
}
public void appendmessage(String msg){
CustomerQuestion = CustomerQuestion +" "+ msg;
}
```

Main.java:

```
Customer  _Customer =new Customer();
Request_Message Request= new Request_Message;
_Customer.setCustomerQuestion(Request.getInput());
String _string=Request.getInput();
_Customer.appendmessage(_string);
String str=__Customer.getCustomerQuestion();
System.out.println("now new Question() is"+str);
```

When I write ram then press enter after again when I write singh it show result: ram ram on console.
I want to show display ram singh as a string.
`public class Request_Message {
{
private String _Input;

public void setInput (String line)
    {
        _Input = line;
    }
    public String getInput()
    {
        return _Input;
    }`

It takes the input from a chat window.

Comment: There is no such object as `__Customer`? Also very strange naming scheme of instance variables. Capital letters?

Comment: Why do you use getCustomerQuestion on an object named _ITChatParticipant when you use _Customer everywhere else in your example? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown what `Request.getInput()` does. I *suspect* that's the problem. What happens if you run:

```
System.out.println(Request.getInput());
System.out.println(Request.getInput());
```

and enter the two different strings?

If you could post a short but *complete* program, we could definitely work out what's going on.

(On a side note, if you follow normal Java naming conventions it's likely to be easier for others to follow your code.)

Comment: @singh: It's hard to help, given that it's clearly a problem in `Request.getInput()` and you've given us no information *at all* about what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation. Use a proper [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead.

```
private StringBuffer customerQuestion = new StringBuffer();

public void appendmessage(String msg){
    customerQuestion.append(msg);
}

public String getCustomerQuestion() {
    return customerQuestion.toString();
}
```

Granted, this is probably not the cause of your specific issue (for that matter see Jon Skeet's answer), but this might be a bottleneck in the future. A `StringBuffer` is the proper way of having a `String` and concatenating text to it over time.

Comment: It's not at all clear whether that's appropriate, and it certainly doesn't explain the behaviour the OP is seeing.

Comment: Its better to delete this post, before somebody come and suggest `StringBuilder`. ;)

Comment: String concatenation being a "bottleneck" in this application is certainly going to be the least of the OPs problems